# What do you call a name that is pronounced differently than expected?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a name that is pronounced differently than most people expect? This can happen with names of people or places, where the owner of the name, or the residents of the place, get to pick the pronunciation, since it's "their" name.

For example:

Versailles in Kentucky, USA is pronounced vur-SAILS, not ver-SIGH. Anglicization of French names is frequent in English-speaking countries, but it is often unexpected, especially when the French pronunciation is so commonly known.

Michaela pronounces her name as Michelle (mih-KAY-luh becomes mih-SHELL).

Bervely pronounces her name as Beverly.

I don't know if there is a such a word, but it might be used like this: "Versailles, Kentucky is an *unexpectonym*."

Comment: One expression is [counterintuitive pronunciations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_places_in_the_United_Kingdom_with_counterintuitive_pronunciations)

Comment: This - *Versailles, Kentucky is an unexpectonym.* - suggests that the town in Kentucky is an *unexpectonym* (great word, I'd stick with it) whereas it's actually the name of that town which has the unexpected pronunciation.  Unless you actually do define *unexpectonym* to mean *a place which is an unexpectonym has a name which is pronounced in an unexpected fashion* which is a heavy load for a single word.

Comment: Why do you find this strange?  English speakers call 'Paree' 'Paris', while French speakers call 'Lorndres' the city English speakers call 'Lundon' and spell ('London').  If you want a posh name for it, try 'xenoprophora' (pronunciation by foreigners). Or you could try 'anglophonetic', given that English speakers, with their famously limited propensity for engagement with other languages, tend to anglicise every foreign place name we encounter.

Comment: There is no such word currently; make one up if you need it. Of course, everybody's expectations and intuitions vary considerably, so pronunciations one might find unexpected could be totally normal for others, depending. Especially for the nameholders.